Perl unpack command works diffrently in Unix and Linux?
I am trying to use unpack logic of perl in unix and Linux, But see it sa huge diffrence when I iterate all the input binary string , Not sure how to solve the issue ??? or is platform related ???
$binaryString = "\x00\x00\x00\x00";

so my code in Unix
$intval = unpack("i*", $binaryString);

This returns 0 as expected.
When I run the same in Linux, it gives a large value. In order to fix this issue I read only the last bytes
unpack("i*", substr($binaryString,3,1))

This returns 0 as expected.
But if the Binary String contains the value
$binaryString = "\x00\x00\x89\x9d";

Unix return 35229 but Linux its return only 157 as I am reading the last character...But I want the same value 35229 in Linux

Unix is a family of operating systems, which includes Linux. So your Linux vs. Unix dichotomy doesn't make sense. What is the actual other operating system?

This is unllikely to be an OS issue, it's more likely to be a CPU difference, because of differences in endianness.

is there any possible fix ??

Use a format character that specifies whether it should be big-endian or little-endian, as appropriate for the data. See the documentation

It could also be a size issue. The docs for pack (which describe the format specifiers) say that i is at least 32 bits, and the emphasis on 'at least' is in the docs, not added by me. To provide more specific help I believe we will need to know the CPU architecture of both systems and the specific OS and variant (in case one of them is a 32-bit system installed on 64-bit-capable hardware, for example).

Use L, l, V or v instead of i to get platform-indrpendent results.

Or N. The choice depends on what the format of your number is. N is 32 bits, big-endian, unsigned. This gives your desired result for both "\0\0\0\0" and "\0\0\x89\x9d", which I presume is what you are really trying to decode. But one of the format specifiers given by pts may be more appropriate to your actual use case.

@Barmar, While Unix is a family of OS, GNU/Linux is technically not part of it. It's right there in the name (GNU = GNU's Not UNIX).  It's merely Unix-like. We do misuse the Unix trademark in common speech, but that would make no sense here as you point out. That said, your point stands. Unix isn't one specific system.

@ikegami In anything other than a legal/trademark context, it's a Unix. In technical discussions, they're close enough.

@Barmar, No, it does not conform to the spec. But I already explained that's irrelevant. You claim they can't be compared because they're both Unix, but that only makes sense if you use incorrect definitions, so that claim is false. You can compare Linux with Unix. For example, Unix systems have pax, and Linux does not.

@ikegami I'm just saying that pack/unpack are not dependent on whether it's Unix, Windows, Linux, etc. They don't have any OS dependency at all, they depend on the hardware.

@Barmar, It can depend on the OS, actually. For example, the size of long and thus the size of L!/L!</L!>/l!/l!</l!> can be different in Linux and Windows on the same hardware. It can also depend on the compiler, compiler settings, and Perl's build configuration.

We have a 32-bit signed or unsigned integer in big-endian byte order.
Also, we're communicating across different machines, so we can't rely on native sizes and byte order if we want the same code on both machines.
Therefore, we should use l> if signed, or L> if unsigned.
I looked up on the appropriate formats on the table found at Formats for Packing and Unpacking Numbers.


Perl unpack command works diffrently in Unix and Linux?

i is for an int, and what an int is can vary by system. It can vary in three ways:

Size (It must be able to represent at least -32,767 to +32,767, but it can be larger.)
Byte order (Little-endian, big-endian, other)
Representation of negative numbers (Two's complement, ones' complement, signed magnitude)

From the information you provided, the byte order used by both systems is different. The size of int on the two systems also appears to be different from the information you provided, but I'm skeptical. Finally, the representation of negative numbers is probably the same on both machine since I believe Perl only runs on machines that use two's complement.
